# Passing variable values in GMAIL API Get Calls

Tags: python, api, get, gmail

so I am trying to get a message by using the GMAIL API. Doing so requires me to provide a messageID. I have stored several message IDs in a local list. However when I try to pass on the list-element as in iterative to the GET request it will simply use the variable value as a string and not the variable itself.
Is there any way to circumvent that? I.e. replace id='str(s) by the actual number '12345234534' from the variable

```
for s in ID_List:
    req_result = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id='str(s)').execute()
```

returns the following error:

```
    File "redacted", line 60, in main
    req_result = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id='str(s)').execute()
  File "redacted\Python39\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "redacted\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/str%28s%29?alt=json returned "Invalid id value". Details: "Invalid id value">
```

Is it possbile that the Gmail API won't let me pass on variables as query-string?

THank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
req_result = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=s).execute()
```

Comment: Sadly did not work, different error message:
<HttpError 404 when requesting <...> returned "Requested entity was not found.". Details: "Requested entity was not found.

Comment: @Manuel Can i see the requested URL please? It's saying this either because the requested message doesn't exist, or the id you passed needs to be in a different format.

Comment: certainly GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{id}

whenever I substitute the id for a real existing one (hard coded) it works just fine, its the variable that poses my problem

Comment: I figured it out, can be closed